# Can i have a hive external table partition search recursively

Tags: hive

So I have a table with external partitions by day. I'm creating partitions as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> ADD PARTITION(year = 2012, month = 5, day = 6) LOCATION 'hdfs://<namenode>/<path>/protos/2012/05/06';
```

only the sequence files are actually in a number of directories under that location. Can I make this work with some wildcards in that path or a switch somewhere?

Comment: i wanna know why a number of directories under that location. why not add sub directories to your partition? for instance, `ALTER TABLE <table> ADD PARTITION(year = 2012, month = 5, day = 6, hour=1) LOCATION 'hdfs://<namenode>/<path>/protos/2012/05/06/1'`;

Comment: the sub directories aren't regular partitions. They're actually the output of map reduce jobs that get dumped in during the day, the directory names being derived from timestamp of the job.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this requires either [HIVE-1083](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1083) or [HIVE-951](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-951), which are both currently unresolved.

Please do tell if you found any way to resolve this, however!

I'll try to update this answer if/once one of these issues is resolved or I find another workaround...

Comment: Sadly, these jira feature requests have been open for at least 5 years.